# Access function in class which is created with the mozilla (rhino) js.jar

Tags: java, servlets, mozilla, rhino

I created a file.js file having code "function func(x,y) {return x+y;}"
and compiled with the command "java org.mozilla.javascrit.tools.jsc.Main file.js". Which resulted in file.class. How do I access / get values of function func in java code ?

Comment: Note: Java is server side scripting, whereas JavaScript is client side. Also java code in java applets also executes on client side i.e. inside web browsers. If you are looking for server side code then sadly it is not possible, however there can be a work around for it. Kindly brief more about the requirements, also show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi Arvind, thanks for your reply / comment.

Currently I am doing 

I create .js file with following code 
"function func(s,x,y) {s.append(x+y);} func(ss,xx,yy);"

Comment: extract of java servlet code goes like this 

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
ScriptEngineManager srpEngMng = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine scrEng = srpEngMng.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
Bindings bnd = scrEng.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
int i1=5;
int i2=10;
try {
 bnd.put("ss", sb);
 bnd.put("xx", i1);
 bnd.put("yy", i2);
 scrEng.eval(r, bnd);
 out.println(sb);
}catch(ScriptException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}

Comment: Here each time when the servlet get called, engine compiles and execute the bite code. 

To optimize this, I want to pre compile the js code / file (only once) and store it some where, and execute the bite code every time when servlet get called. And there is a reason to do this.